# Yeoman angular project looks different in grunt vs grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman

I am fairly new to building out projects using Yeoman. I have been able to build out my project to put onto a server using grunt. But I have some radio buttons on the page and when I use grunt-serve, they are styled with spacing, but when I run grunt and move the files onto my server, all of the spacing for the radio buttons is gone. Anyone know of a css style that might not come with the grunt build?

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" ng-model="formData.q1" ng-change="totalValues()" class="labelNumber">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" ng-model="formData.q1" ng-change="totalValues()" class="labelNumber">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" ng-model="formData.q1" ng-change="totalValues()" class="labelNumber">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" ng-model="formData.q1" ng-change="totalValues()" class="labelNumber">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" ng-model="formData.q1" ng-change="totalValues()" class="labelNumber">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guesss your html files are minified by the grund build. And html process a line break as a space.
To keep space characters between your radios you can do :

```
<input type="radio">&nbsp;
<input type="radio">&nbsp;
<input type="radio">&nbsp;
```

`&nbsp;` means `non breakable space`.

Comment: I didn't have a line break. I was thinking it had css that kept the spacing for the radio buttons from either Angular or Bootstrap (I have seen some posts that talk about fonts and glyphs not being held from Bootstrap). I am curious to know where the css is lost, gonna keep digging into the spacing issue I guess. I was hoping someone knew if either library had css that could be left out in the grunt process? I don't like the extra markup of the nbsp either.